# What substring algorithm (to find a string) does PHP use?

Tags: php, c, algorithm, substring

I have been trying to figure out what substring algorithm (to find a string in another string). PHP uses, I have found the following piece of code in the PHP source on GitHub:

I think it uses Bruteforce, but I am not sure, that's why I seek some help on SO.

```
zend_memnstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle, size_t needle_len, const char *end) {
    const char *p = haystack;
    const char ne = needle[needle_len-1];
    ptrdiff_t off_p;
    size_t off_s;

    if (needle_len == 1) { 
        return (const char *)memchr(p, *needle, (end-p));
    }

    off_p = end - haystack;
    off_s = (off_p > 0) ? (size_t)off_p : 0;

    if (needle_len > off_s) {
        return NULL;
    }

    if (EXPECTED(off_s < 1024 || needle_len < 3)) {
        end -= needle_len;

        while (p <= end) {
            if ((p = (const char *)memchr(p, *needle, (end-p+1))) && ne == p[needle_len-1]) {
                if (!memcmp(needle, p, needle_len-1)) {
                    return p;
                }
            }
            if (p == NULL) {
               return NULL;
            }
            p++;
        }
        return NULL;
    } else {
        return zend_memnstr_ex(haystack, needle, needle_len, end);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a [Naïve string search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm#Na.C3.AFve_string_search) algorithm to me

Comment: Note that `zend_memnstr_ex` is called for longer strings. This function uses the [Sunday algorithm](http://www.inf.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/pattern/sundayen.htm).

Comment: Note that the code invokes undefined behavior if `needle_len` is `0` instead of returning `haystack`.

Answer (score 0):

The function follows these steps:

- It loads the last character of the `needle` into `ne`, thereby invoking undefined behavior if `needle_len` is `0`.  This byte will be used for the generic loop later in the code.
- It special cases the case of `needle_len == 1`, delegating the seach to standard library function `memchr`.
- It computes the length of the memory chunk to scan, allowing for `end` to point before `haystack` and returning NULL in this case.  This is inconsistent, since this consistency check is only performed for `needle_len != 1` and `memchr would be passed a huge length of`end - haystack`if`end`points before`haystack` potentially invoking undefined behavior.
- For a length less than `1023` or a `needle_len` less than `3`, the function implements a naive algorithm in terms of `memchr`.  It scans for the first byte of `needle`, manually checks the last byte of the potential match and uses `memcmp` to verify the rest of the potential match.  This method is inconsistent: if `needle_len` is `2`, a simpler scan would be more efficient, and if all cases, one less byte should be passed to `memcmp` since the first byte already matches.
- For other cases, `haystack` length longer than 1022 and `needle` longer than 2 bytes, the function uses another method implemented in `zend_memnstr_ex`, which `nwellnhof` indicates is a variation of the Sunday algorithm.

For more explanations about the different methods for efficient string search:

- a general article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm
- details on the Sunday algorithm: http://www.inf.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/pattern/sundayen.htm